# Heroku build script repeating

Tags: node.js, heroku, react-fullstack

I'm attempting to get into full stack web dev, so I followed [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/) tutorial. I'm trying to deploy to heroku now, but whenever I deploy (following instructions on heroku's own website), the build fails. The output looks something like this:

```
   > fullstacktest@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_84ca5816
   > cd client && npm install && npm run build

   audited 50 packages in 1.094s
   found 0 vulnerabilities

   > fullstacktest@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_84ca5816
   > cd client && npm install && npm run build

   audited 50 packages in 0.752s
   found 0 vulnerabilities

   > fullstacktest@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_84ca5816
   > cd client && npm install && npm run build

   audited 50 packages in 0.904s
   found 0 vulnerabilities
```

This goes on seemingly forever. I tried just letting it do its thing, but after 15mins it was still doing this.
The structure for my project is this:

```
client   /app.js (react)
         /node_modules
server   /index.js (node with express)
package.json
package-lock.json
node_modules
```

Here's the package.json with  simple build instructions

```
  "name": "fullstacktest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.6"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've been looking online for other people that have this problem but I have found nothing.
Thanks for taking the time to read this,
Maiko

Comment: Which commands are you using to deploy and are you using the heroku cli?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Here are all the commands I issued:
git init

heroku git:remote -a testapp

git add .

git commit -am "make it better"

git push heroku master

These are taken from heroku's own website in the deploy instructions with the heroku CLI

Comment: Seems all good to me. And can't find a problem in the package.json file too.

Comment: If everything looks good, I'll try switching hosting services. Thinking about using Vercel or maybe AWS.

Comment: I want you to try `npm i -g heroku` again. This will fix any problems with heroku. And if that doesn't work then try adding a remote origin to a github repo maybe

Comment: Cause even I have a project deployed [spend-elons-money](https://spend-elons-money.herokuapp.com) and I had first made a github repo for it [Github Repo](https://github.com/CodeFingers809/spend-elons-money)

Comment: Trying that now. I'm also trying to deploy with Vercel, but I'm getting the same error. I'm going to try reinstalling git and nodejs to see if the problem lies there.

Comment: After the heroku reinstall pushing to master returned:
src refspec master does not match any

Then I pushed to main instead and I'm getting the same error as before. Reinstalling git and node now

Comment: Heroku, git and node reinstall did nothing. Given that this project is only boilerplate, I'm just going to delete it and restart. Bit annoying that this happened, but I'm glad it happened sooner rather than later. 
Thank you for your help, Code Fingers!

Comment: I am extremely sorry for responding so late and also not being able to solve your issue. But, did you try making github repo and adding a remote origin?